# Integer field in a type does not parse request parameter in java web service

Tags: java, web-services

Why does Integer field couldn't get the value that i sent. If i use Integer parameter by itself (like sending an ID) in WebMethod works fine.

Also the String field can get the value that i sent without any problem.

Here is the web service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "testWS")
public class testWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Hello")
    public Integer Hello(@WebParam(name = "testData") TEST testData) {
            return testData.getINTPROP();
    }
}
```

TEST type definition:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TEST {

    private Integer INTPROP;//making public also didn't work

    public Integer getINTPROP() {
        return INTPROP;
    }

    public void setINTPROP(Integer INTPROP) {
        this.INTPROP = INTPROP;
    }

    private String STRINGPROP;

    public String getSTRINGPROP() {
        return STRINGPROP;
    }

    public void setSTRINGPROP(String STRINGPROP) {
        this.STRINGPROP = STRINGPROP;
    }
}
```

C# consumer application:

```
...
test f = new test();

f.INTPROP = 123;
f.STRINGPROP = "abcdef";

var ff = ws.Hello(f);//returns 0
```

I hope i could explained my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Marking field with @XmlSchemaType solved my problem.

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
public Integer INTPROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the setter to String.

public void setINTPROP(String INTPROP) {
        this.INTPROPString = INTPROP;

Then change the String to an integrer with another function.
Return it as an integer, this should solve the problem.

Comment: Use private String, instead of Public VoIP.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but creating string fields is problematic because of these classes being shared.

Comment: Can you create an additional class that converts from a String to an integer. Then just pass the value to the function. I believe you are sending two Strings, and not a String and an integer. Can you post the Soap ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another aproach:

Add this function. Java should be able to handle this.

If the Variable you are passing is a integer, then the function you have will be used. If it is a String, Then this function will be called:

```
public String setINTPROP(String INTPROP) {
    this.INTPROP = Integer.valueOf(INTPROP);
```